# PHP issue about sending mail message

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue when sending e-mail using php code. I have a form which sends an attachment to a folder and the name of the attachment to the database, in order to then send the link of the file inside the message.

The problem is that the file and all the rest go the way it should but I can't seem to create the link.

Here is the code:

```
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$to = $_REQUEST['to'] ;
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
$message = ''.$_REQUEST['message'].'<a href="http://lamyse.net/images/'.$file_name.'"> download</a>';



$sql="SELECT file  FROM login_admin WHERE user_name='dori'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


$file_name = $row['file'];}
    
  
mail($to, $subject, $message, "From:" . $email);
 
$photo =$_FILES['file']['name'];

$target = "images/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get `$file_name` until a few lines after you try to use it. Quick fix would be to move

```
$message = ''.$_REQUEST['message'].'<a href="http://lamyse.net/images/'.$file_name.'"> download</a>';
```

below your `while` loop.

Comment: Hey thank you very much, it works :)
One last question please, when i do it, the print comes out like this...   <a href="http://lamyse.net/images/CiviReport.pdf"> download</a> when it should be just the Download...clickable..

Comment: @Al_12 check how your quotes are structures. Looks like they are ordered wrong therefore making the html break. Could be something in `$_REQUEST['message']`. If this answer helped you should accept it.

Comment: Well thanks very much for everything :) of course i'm going to accept the answer. thanks!